# How to merge variables of type hash across different variable files in ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, automation, yaml

I have two YAML variable files which are reused for many playbooks:

```
# playbook/group_vars/all

settings:
  a: 1
  b: 2

# inventory/group_vars/main.yml

settings:
  c: 3
```

I want `settings` to be equal `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }` in my playbooks.

Instead it equals `{ c: 3 }` because `inventory/group_vars/*` has
higher priority than `playbook/group_vars/all` and because hashes are *overridden*, not *merged*.

### I see the following options:

- Define variables separately, using naming conventions and prefixes, instead of using hashes, like so:

  ```
  # playbook/group_vars/all

  settings_a: 1
  settings_b: 2

  # inventory/group_vars/main.yml

  settings_c: 3
  ```

Our team does not consider this solution elegant enough.

- Use set_fact and/or Jinja's "+" operator

`{{ list_common + list_specific }}`

This requires changes in many playbooks (we do have many of them) and also looks bad.

--

**Are there other options to merge hashes from different files instead of redefining (overriding) them?**

What we are trying to achieve is to stop duplicating lists across variable files and define only those parameters which are specific to the group/host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, list is `[1, 2, 3]` and you talk about dictionary `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` or in other words hash.

There is configurable parameter: [hash_behaviour](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour).

By default it is `replace`, but you can set it to `merge` to achieve desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Well, hash_behaviour seems just right for my case! Thank you.

Comment: Update 2021. The `hash_behaviour` is deprecated since ansible 2.10 https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/a7x92q/in_which_case_hash_behaviourmerge_can_become/ec8mf7f/ So we'll go with separate variables having the same prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ansible v2.0 you can do it:

```
- name: merging hash_a and hash_b into hash_c
  set_fact: hash_c="{{ hash_a|combine(hash_b) }}"
```

Check more under [Ansible filters - Combining hashes/dictionaries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) (coming from Jinja2)